# Jaeger Service not shown in Jaeger UI

Tags: opentracing, jaeger

I installed the jaeger all in one in Docker with:

```
docker run --rm --name jaeger -p 5775:5775/udp -p 6831:6831/udp -p 6832:6832/udp -p 5778:5778 -p  16686:16686 -p 14267:14267 -p 14268:14268 -p 9411:9411 jaegertracing/all-in-one:1.7
```

And below is the sample code on how I initialize the tracer and spans. 
I get the logs in my console but it does not reflect in my Jaeger UI.

Could anyone please help me with this?

```
logging = new LoggingReporter();

SamplerConfiguration sampler = new SamplerConfiguration();
sampler.withType("const");
sampler.withParam(1);

ReporterConfiguration reporter = new ReporterConfiguration();
reporter.withLogSpans(true);
reporter.withSender(sender);        

tracer = Configuration.fromEnv("sample_jaeger").withSampler(sampler).withReporter(reporter).getTracer();

Scope scope = tracer.buildSpan("parent-span").startActive(true);
Tags.SAMPLING_PRIORITY.set(scope.span(), 1);
scope.span().setTag("this-is-test", "YUP");

logging.report((JaegerSpan) scope.span());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you closing the tracer and the scope? If you are using a version before 0.32.0, you should manually call `tracer.close()` before your process terminates, otherwise the spans in the buffer might not get dispatched.

As for the scope, it's common to wrap it in a try-with-resources statement:

```
try (Scope scope = tracer.buildSpan("parent-span").startActive(true)) {
  Tags.SAMPLING_PRIORITY.set(scope.span(), 1);
  scope.span().setTag("this-is-test", "YUP");

  logging.report((JaegerSpan) scope.span());
}
```

You might also want to check the OpenTracing tutorial at https://github.com/yurishkuro/opentracing-tutorial or the Katacoda-based version at https://www.katacoda.com/courses/opentracing

**-- EDIT**

> and is deployed on a different hostname and port

Then you do need to tell the tracer where to send the traces. Either export the `JAEGER_ENDPOINT` environment variable, pointing to a collector endpoint, or set `JAEGER_AGENT_HOST`/`JAEGER_AGENT_PORT`, with the location of the agent. You can check the available environment variables for your client on the following URL: https://www.jaegertracing.io/docs/1.7/client-features/

Comment: Hi @jpkrohling. Yes, I already checked the tutorials. I also made another project with a Spring boot setup and deployed in my localhost:8080. Everything went well. However, this project I am working on does not use Spring boot and is deployed on a different hostname and port. I really think that is the cause of the issue I am having. Do you know what other setup I should apply if the project is on a different hostname and port from where the jaeger is deployed in the docker? Thanks.

Comment: I just updated the answer based on your new information